# French analogs to EngVid.com?

Tags: ressources, apprentissage

Actually, my question is in the title. EngVid.com with very its cool educational videos is really nice for studying English. Just some themes connected with English, interesting talks which are fun to watch, but still educational.

Does anyone know any French-language analogs to it? Or something similar to it?

Comment: Especially fast French with accurate French subtitles - very hard to find.  But if I could find some it might help me to understand the ways in which French people mix the word sounds together and shorten them.

Comment: @Jez Oh, I've been learning French for ~3 months. You said "especially fast French with accurate French subtitiles" -- I'm not ready for fast French :) Actually, you wrote it in that way like you know some sites with nonfast French or smth... Do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know EngVid.com mainly from its YouTube channel and I have been looking for similar channels to list them on my [website](http://cstrobbe.github.io/languagelearning/french/index.html#general).

There are several good channels for learning French, but not all of them have subtitles.

With subtitles:

- [Français Authentique](https://www.youtube.com/user/francaisauthentique) (and its [website](https://www.francaisauthentique.com/)). For example, the playlist [T'as 5 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFjbBR3UHcAJh77c6CUfS1OR7YYTdzmnD) has a large number of videos that are just 5 minutes long.
- [Français avec Pierre](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVgW9ZQaGBk6fsiPgE2mYDg): the videos usually have French subtitles (except for some of the oldest videos; more recent videos have subtitles in several languages). For a playlist specifically aimed at beginners, see [Podcasts pour débutants](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcoQWyFpRIxibMTK7HlVrGrm9WHpVQiHX).

Without subtitles:

- [Nathalie FLE](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNFH_L59UnA39jb7SufQh3Q).
- [Home Language](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFu6uJDqU_6vCIyN9KpMPLg).

Comment: wow, great site, good job! I will definitely use it. Thank you!

Comment: I've noticed your website is on github directly. Is that a facility provided to all github users or do you need any level of activity in order to be afforded such facilities? Thanks.

Comment: @Galèrefranquiste I am using a service known as [GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/). I use only static HTML, CSS and occasionally a bit of JavaScript. Server-scripts are not supported.